# MySQL Trigger duplicate data

Tags: mysql, triggers

i had query like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER `tambah_riwayatobat` AFTER INSERT ON `obat`
FOR EACH ROW insert into riwayat_obat(nama, keterangan, distributor,tanggal)
(select new.nama, 'Masuk', d.nama ,now()
From distributor d
join obat ON new.id_distributor = d.id_distributor)
```

i try to insert data with trigger and one of part data i fetch with constraint, but why the data be duplicate entry ?

Output :

[image]

example, if i try to insert data obat 1st time, data on tambah_riwayatobat insert 1 too

if i try to insert data obat 2nd time, data on tambah_riwayatobat insert 2 times with same data

if i try to insert data obat 3rd time, data on tambah_riwayatobat insert 3 times with same data

Comment: (1) All your trigger does is insert into another table.  It doesn't stop any insertions.  (2) If you want to prevent duplicates, use a unique constraint or index.

Comment: can you fix my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain *exactly* what's happening, but it's a result of the join in your trigger code. You’re joining `obat` to `distributor`, but your join *condition* makes no mention of `obat` so you're getting some sort of cross-product where on the second and subsequent `INSERT` your `SELECT` subquery is selecting more than one row.

You shouldn't (and don't need to) use the join, since all the data you need from `obat` is already in the pseudorecord **`NEW`**. The following code should work much better:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `tambah_riwayatobat`
  AFTER INSERT ON `obat`
  FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO riwayat_obat
        (nama, keterangan, distributor, tanggal)
      (SELECT NEW.nama, 'Masuk', d.nama, now()
        FROM distributor d
        WHERE new.id_distributor = d.id_distributor
        LIMIT 1);
```

The `LIMIT` clause will ensure that the `SELECT` selects only one row, so the `INSERT` inserts only one row; if `distributor.id_distributor` is a primary key the `LIMIT` clause is unnecessary.